# Problema en conexión a mi base de datos con php

Tags: php, mysql

He realizado varias conexiones a mi base de datos con `php` utilizando *PDO* de la siguiente manera (estoy utilizando MVC):

```php
class Conexion
{

    public static function conectar()
    {

        try
        {
            $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=marmar_textiles','root','');
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            $e->getMessage();
        }

        return $conexion;
    }

}
```

Y al tratar de realizar la siguiente consulta en mi **Model**:

```php
// Incluimos el archivo donde se encuentra la conexion
require_once("conexion.php");

class Datos
{
    public static function ingresoUsuarioModel($datosModel)
    {
        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE usuario = :usuario");
        $stmt->bindParam(":usuario", $datosModel['usuario'], PDO::PARAM_STR);

        if($stmt->execute())
        {
            return $stmt->fetchAll();
        }
        else
        {
            return "error";
        }


    }
}
```

Me salen los siguientes errores, los cuales no entiendo porque me dice que no esta definida en la linea del return:

> Notice: Undefined variable: conexion
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare()

*NOTA:* Estoy utilizando un host virtual de `Wampp`.

Comment: He replicado tu ejercicio sin problemas, sería interesante que verifiques que la ruta de tu `require_once()` sea la correcta

Comment: @Aprendiz si es la correcta, ambos se encuentran en la misma carpeta